# Unable to add custom properties to an Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

Excel workbooks have a `CustomDocumentProperties` collection. This collection is of type `DocumentProperties` and has an `Add` method that I'm attempting to call from MATLAB.

If I call the `invoke` method on the collection I see:

```
>> workbook.CustomDocumentProperties.invoke
    Item = handle Item(handle, Variant, int32)
    Add = handle Add(handle, string, bool, int32, Variant(Optional))
```

I assume this means the `Add` method requires a string, boolean, `int32`, and an optional variant, and this matches with the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.DocumentProperties.Add) for the `Add` method.

However, all combination of inputs I've tried to this function result in an error. For example:

```
workbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add('MyProp', true, int32(1), true);
```

Results in the error:

```
Invoke Error: Incorrect number of arguments
```

If I supply 7 or more arguments then I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid number is arguments. This method can take maximum 6 arguments
```

If I supply anything other than a string as the first argument I get the error:

```
No method 'Add' with matching signature found for class 'Interface.2DF8D04D_5BFA_101B_BDE5_00AA0044DE52'.
```

Has anyone successfully used this function to add a custom property to an Excel workbook from MATLAB?